# asp.net mvc wizard form with xval

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xval

im using linqtosql and xval to validate server side and client side. im trying to do a wizard style form but cant pass the  actual values accross different actions.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices: store the values in TempData, store the valus in the Session, or write the temporary values to hidden fields in the view and reload them at each step.